# Trying to read a PNG and xuggler

Tags: java, transparency, javax.imageio, xuggler

Im using xuggler to put a transparent mask in a video.

Im trying to open a valid png using the ImageIO.read(), but when it renders, theres always a white backgroun in my picture.

This is my code for reading.

```
        url = new URL(stringUrl);
        imagem = ImageIO.read(url);
        boolean hasAlpha = imagem.getColorModel().hasAlpha();
```

This boolean is always false.

And in Xuggler when i make the render

mediaReader
            .setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

What im doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know Xuggler, but `BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` can't hold alpha. You need to use a type like  `BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` or `TYPE_INT_ARGB` to get alpha. Also, it seems your PNG is not transparent, but we can't reproduce that, unless you also provide the test image you are using.

Comment: Thanks haraldK. The png picture opens fine (with transparent background) in Windows Image Viewer. But, when I open it in Illustrator, theres a white border on picture.

Comment: Thanks haraldK. The png picture opens fine (with transparent background) in Windows Image Viewer. But, when I open it in Illustrator, theres a white border on picture.

So, I make a image ON ILLUSTRATOR, saving as png, and it works fine. 

Checking in my code, i notice that the image that works its from the type  TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR  , and the one who DOESNT works its of type TYPE_3BYTE_BGR.

Theres other thing, when I debug it, I see that the png that doesnt works have  #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3. And the one who works hava #pixelBits = 32 numComponents = 4.

Comment: That makes sense. There's something special about the original PNG then. If you'd share the original image and the "fixed" one, I'd probably be able to tell you what is different and why the second works. :-)

Comment: This is the original image: 

http://www.4shared.com/download/yVFg70W4ba/avatar.png?lgfp=3000

And the "fixed one" (just a circle i made in Illustrator). 

http://www.4shared.com/download/dYKEl62mce/200.png?lgfp=3000

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" with your original image file, is that it is a 24 bit RGB (3 channel) PNG, with a `tRNS` chunk.

The `tRNS` chunk specifies a color (`255, 255, 255`, or white, in this case) that is to be replaced with fully transparent pixels. In effect, applying this transparency works kind of like a bit mask, where all pixels are either fully transparent or fully opaque. However, being an ["ancillary" (optional, or non-critical) chunk according to the PNG specificiation](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.Anc-chunks), PNG decoders may choose to ignore this information.

Unfortunately, it seems like the default `PNGImageReader` (the "PNG plugin") for ImageIO does not apply this bit mask, and instead keeps the image in fully opaque RGB (which is still spec compliant behavior).

Your second image file is a 32 bit RGBA (4 channels incl. alpha). In this case, any reader must (and does) decode all channels, including the full 8 bit alpha channel. ImageIO's `PNGImageReader` does decode this with the expected transparency.

---

PS: It is probably possibly to "fix" the transparency from your first image, using the [meta data](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata.html).

The meta data for your image contains the following information in the [native PNG format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/png_metadata.html):

```
<javax_imageio_png_1.0>
    ....
    <tRNS>
        <tRNS_RGB red="255" green="255" blue="255"/>
    </tRNS>
</javax_imageio_png_1.0>
```

After parsing this, you could convert the image, by first creating a new 4 channel image (like `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR`), copying the R, G and B channels to this new image, and finally set the alpha channel to either `0` for (all pixels that match the transparent color), or `255` (for all others).

PPS: You probably want to perform these operations directly on the `Raster`s, as using the `BufferedImage.getRGB(..)/setRGB(..)` methods will convert the values to an `sRGB` color profile, which may not exactly match the RGB value from the `tRNS` chunk.

There you go! :-)

Comment: Perfect Harald, i talked with my partners at this job, and they correct it. Thanks a lot for the atention. You rule!

Comment: Good stuff! Don't forget to upvote/accept if this answer was helpful. :-)